# Vue.js nested routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nested-routes

My Current Route is

```
function route(path, view) {
return {
    path: path,
    meta: meta[path],
    component: resolve => import(`pages/${view}View.vue`).then(resolve)
   }
}

route('/', 'Home'),
route('/help', 'Help),
route('/blog', 'BlogList'),
route('/blog/:slug', 'BlogDetails'),
```

Now Everything is working fine. but when I visit `/blog/:slug` route and from that component when I click back to `/help` from button Route pattern is `/blog/help` not the `/help`.

Comment: This is why it is important to nest your routes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See my [jsfiddle Vuejs route](https://jsfiddle.net/smekalin/8vqneL18/4) , I mean this help you.

```js
const Home = {
        template: '<h1>Home</h1>'
    };

    const Help = {
        template: '<h1>Help</h1>'
    };

    const Profile = {
        template: '<h1>Profile</h1>'
    };

    const User = {
        template: '<h1>User</h1>'
    };

    routes = [
        {path: '/', component: Home},
        {path: '/help', component: Help},
        {path: '/user', component: User},
        {path: '/user/:id', component: {
            render(h) {
                return h(
                    'h1',
                    { style: {color: 'skyblue'} },
                    `User id: ${this.$route.params.id}`
                );
            }
        }}
    ];

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes
    });

    new Vue({
        router
    }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
   <div id="app">
        <router-link :to='{path: "/"}'>/</router-link> <br>
        <router-link :to='{path: "/help"}'>/help</router-link> <br>
        <router-link :to='{path: "/user"}'>/user</router-link> <br>
        <router-link :to='{path: "/user/userid"}'>/user/userID</router-link>
        {{$route.path}}
        <router-view></router-view>
        <br>
        <button @click='$router.go(-1)'>go back</button>
        <button @click='$router.go(1)'>go forward</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: it would be great if you add some explanation as well what was the issue and why its not working with his code , so in future it can be helpful to him as well for better understanding of concept.

Comment: I advise you to read documentation that it became clear how it is better to do. You may begin to read "Essentials" and "Advanced > lazy-loading" for resolving your issue. Docs: https://router.vuejs.org/en/ .

Comment: its not about me or you we should think about question and how we can help the user.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya oh, I thought you are author of the question, sorry:) I don’t know why the user did it like above. I tried to show other way for resolve this issue. When we read documentation we understand the better way, so I gave a link.